# CE 1.9.1 mass product update for Special Price To date

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, special-price

In another question thread I was recommended to do a mass product update by selecting all products and choosing "Change attributes" in order to edit the special from/to date for many products at once.

While there is no "Change attributes" item in the top right drop down, there is an "update attributes" item there. Special to date is not one of the editable attributes though. I notice it is listed as a System attribute when looking in the 'manage attributes' screen. Can Special To Date actually be mass edited in the UI in my version?

I guess one could change its value via phpMyadmin in order to make it editable. However I'd like to avoid touching the database directly, if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, *Special Price To Date* is a mass editable attribute – as long as all selected products have it.

That is, as soon as only one item in the selection is assigned to an attribute set or of a product type that does not feature the desired attribute, it will be excluded from the edit form.

To verify, select only one product in the grid that definitely has the particular attribute and run the *Update Attributes* mass action.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. I deselected all product types except Simple and retried with success.